# integral of arccos

Tags: definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Please help me with this definite integral.
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\arccos(x)}{x^2+1}dx
$$
Thanks, have a nice day!

Comment: Try change of variables $x=\cos (t) \implies dx = -\sin (t) dt$.

Comment: @Vlad How does that help?

Comment: thank you, i'm trying to evaluate this now, but it's late and i have no ideea 

$$
\int_0^pi/2 \frac{t*sint}{1+cos^2(t)}dt
$$

Comment: This is a lot more difficult than it looks, according to wolfram alpha, which spits out a result of$$I=\frac 14\biggr[4\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)-4\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-1+\sqrt2\right)+\pi^2+\log\left(17-12\sqrt2\right)\operatorname{arcsinh} 1\biggr]$$

Comment: @CosminAlex Okay first off, where did you get a $p$ and an $i/2$ term?

Comment: I am currently in highschool, the integral is from a admision test from university and the result is pi^2 over 4

Comment: it's pi/2 but latex is beating me right now

Comment: @CosminAlex Yes but the integral you gave evaluates approximately to $0.84$ while $\pi^2/4$ is nowhere near that

Comment: It's neither $\pi^2/4$ nor $\pi/2$.

Comment: @CosminAlex Perhaps you meant$$I=\int\limits_{-1}^{1}dx\,\frac {\arccos x}{1+x^2}=\frac {\pi^2}4$$

Comment: YEEEEEEEEEESSSS, that one

Comment: it is and even function and i've got 2*integral from 0 to 1 of arccos(x) over x^2+1

Comment: i'm sorry for being such a noob..

Comment: but still, how do you evaluate that?

Comment: Hint: $$ \begin{align} \int_{-1}^1\frac{\arccos(x)}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x &=\frac12\int_{-1}^1\frac{\arccos(x)+\arccos(-x)}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\ \end{align} $$

Answer (score 3):

In the comments, the OP has stated that the actual integral is$$I=\int\limits_{-1}^{1}dx\,\frac {\arccos x}{1+x^2}$$

Integration by parts on $u=\arccos x$ gives$$I=\arccos x\arctan x\,\Biggr\rvert_{-1}^1+\int\limits_{-1}^{1}dx\,\frac {\arctan x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$Since the latter integral is odd i.e $f(x)=-f(-x)$, then it is equal to zero. Hence$$I=\arccos x\arctan x\,\Biggr\rvert_{-1}^{1}=\frac {\pi^2}4$$

Comment: thank you for your time :)